# Need of self testabilty code inside embedded firmware modules?

Tags: pic, firmware, testing

I have a question to ask about the self-testability code inside a firmware module.
I have developed code, and it was in a shamble, and I was clueless about firmware architecture too. Later I found great articles about firmware architecture, for example, *[Developing a flexible firmware architecture](http://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4008918/2/Developing-a-flexible-firmware-architecture)*, and they put emphasis on modularizing your firmware in to modules.

I have the firmware with the associated modules:

1. adc_module
2. EEPROM module
3. SPI module
4. Algorithm1 module
5. Algorithm module

I don't have an [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) here, and I found the inclusion of testabilty code inside each firmware inside those articles :D.
Well, I'm working on 8-bit PIC microcontrollers, and I would like to know whether I'm shooting over the head or on the right path.

I would like your suggestions for the 'self test code inclusion'. And if I need to, what sort of functions do they perform inside the modules?

Comment: Why do not have a test scaffold for each module, and then load them into the device separately and test?

Comment: so  i  should load the scaffold only for testing  right?

Comment: You should load the scaffold only when testing the module it's written for. The final product should only have enough code to test what you were unable to test in the individual modules, as well as basic sanity checks.

Comment: I wrote an answer over on Stack Overflow about this topic. It includes a very simple testing strategy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215172/how-to-organise-declarations-and-functions-in-code-h-file-and-includes-for-best/21271122#21271122

Answer (score 3):

I like to think of test firmware of taking three different roles during the lifetime of a product.

When a PCB for a new design is delivered for the first time, one needs to have individual firmware programs to test each separate component of the system.  Each of these are standalone programs, and flashed into the microcontroller individually as needed.  I always start testing one of the UARTs, since this will be the way the results of all the other tests will delivered.  (Even if there is an LCD in the system, that is much more complicated to bring up than a UART, which is integral to the microcontroller and about the only thing that can go wrong is a mistake in the PCB layout.)

If possible, I like to have a dedicated UART in the system just for debugging output.  usually brought out to a header which can be marked DNP (do not place) in production.  If one has to share the debugging port with another functions, some compromises must be made.

In a recent project, I had test firmware for checking voltage rails, a cell module, Bluetooth module, SD card interface, audio circuit (DAC + EEPOT), keyboard, LCD, external interrupts, and parallel port expansion.  Along the way these checked all of the SPI and I2C busses in the system.

Usually a PCB will go through several revisions.  Sometimes the circuit will be changed, sometimes not (just layout issues).  I create a directory for each separate revision, e.g. RevA, RevB etc. and make a complete copy of all the files as I go along in case pinouts have changed and I have to make minor changes to the firmware.

Once the board starts being manufactured, I combine all of the test firmware into a single program, along with a driver which is then flashed into the microcontroller and used by the contract manufacturer to test each PCB after it is assembled.  Once the board has passed all tests, the test firmware is replaced by the production firmware.

The last place test firmware can be included is part of the production program.  I tend not to do this, since a lot of tests such as keyboard, LCD, and audio require a user to be involved, and other tests such as the cell and Bluetooth require a controlled environment.  It still might be useful for example to test all of the voltage rails on startup.  On one project, a fairly complex board had 12 different voltage rails (six just for the LCD).

Answer (score 3):

My usual approach to this is to include a command processor in the firmware that communicates over a bi-directional stream of bytes to a host, usually using the UART.  Most projects include communication to a host, so often you need this code anyway.  In some cases there is no host connection in the final system.  Depending on available resources, you might include the command processor code in the firmware only when so enabled by build-time debug switches.

For example, I'm working on a project right now that will be battery operated and communicate with the rest of the world via MiWi using 802.15 radios only.  Since I had room on the board, I included pads for connecting to the UART lines.  In final production, this connector won't be populated, so adds no additional cost.  Since power drain is very important in the final product, the UART interaface is only enabled if a build-time switch for that purpose is set to debug mode.  Without that switch set the UART is never turned on and the code for it is not even linked in.

Having a simple way to enable/disable the optional UART interface is useful even after the firmware has been debugged.  Some time in the future, features may need to be added or other modifications made.  The UART interface will again be useful for development and testing.  This way, it only takes changing a single "false" to "true" to enable it, and doesn't require having to figure out all over again how to link in the code, add the hooks to the right places, initialize the UART, etc.

Once I have a bi-directional stream of bytes to a host, I usually use a simple packet protocol.  Each packet starts with a opcode byte, followed by whatever data bytes are specified for that opcode.  I call the packets from the host to the unit "commands", and those from the unit to the host "responses", but responses aren't necessarily only sent in direct response to commands.

This kind of opcode-data protocol is easy to parse in the microcontroller (how easy or not it is on a PC is irrelevant, but it is easy there too).  The opcode byte indexes into a dispatch table, which causes a routine specific for that opcode to be executed.  The command routines then get any data bytes of the command, carry out the command, then jump back to the main dispatch loop.  This loop is usually run in a separate task, so appears to run asynchronously and independently from other things in the system.

The command set of course includes commands to make the system perform its intended functions, but also a bunch of debug commands that are not used in the final system.  These are used by a test program on the host to allow testing of low level parts of the firmware.

For example, in the MiWi project I mentioned earlier, the canned MiWi code needs to read and write to the internal EEPROM via a defined interface that I must provide.  To test that inteface separately, I added commands to read and write EEPROM locations.  Using those commands, I tested and verified the low level EEPROM interface.  Finding bugs in that later from strange MiWi symptoms would have been much harder.

I do this so often I have templates for both the command processor in the firmware and the test program on the host.  I usually reserve opcode 0 as NOP, 1 for PING, and 2 for FWINFO.  PING just responds with PONG, which is also a single-byte response.  That can be useful to test the communication link.  FWINFO causes the FWINFO response to be sent, which gives the firmware type, version, and sequence numbers.  Other commands are added from there.

Sometimes it has been useful to have commands for low level operations available in the final system, even though this was not in the spec.  Stuff happens.  More than once having new software be able to read and write EEPROM directly in existing field units, for example, has saved a lot of trouble.  The software people usually scoff at the extra commands at first, then are really thankful a year later when it saves their butts.